# Homotopy classes of self-maps on $\mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider the two inclusions $\eta_i:\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1$. I claim that the following map is injective
$$(\eta_1\sqcup\eta_2)^*:[\mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1,\mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1]\to [\mathbb{S}^1\sqcup\mathbb{S}^1,\mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1].$$
In other words, two self-maps $f,g:\mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1\to \mathbb{S}^1\vee\mathbb{S}^1$ are homotopic if for the restrictions $f_i:=f\circ\eta_i$ and $g_i:=g\circ \eta_i$, we have $f_i\simeq g_i$.

If we would work with based homotopy, the statement would be clear. However, the homotopies $f_1\simeq g_1$ and $f_2\simeq g_2$ may move the base point …

Comment: what is the question? Can you clearly indicate somewhere?

Comment: I am wondering whether my claim is true or not.

Comment: Do your square brackets denote based or unbased homotopy classes?

Comment: Unbased homotopy classes – which seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not injective. I am reference Hatcher's section 4.A1 throughout which talks about basepointed vs. nonbasepointed homotopy classes of maps.

Let $f: S^1 \vee S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \vee S^1$ be $l \vee r$ where $l$ means wrap around the left copy of $S^1$ and $r$ the right, and $g:S^1 \vee S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \vee S^1$ be $l \vee (lr)^{-1}r(lr)$. The image of $[f]$ and $[g]$ under the map is the same since $[l]=[l]$ and $[(lr)^{-1}r(lr)]=[r]$ (since one is the conjugate of the other, see Hatcher).

Now $f$ is not homotopic to $g$ since if they were we could look at the path of the basepoint under such a homotopy. It suffices to show this path, really a loop, does not commute with $[l]:S^1 \rightarrow S^1 \vee S^1$, since then conjugation by this loop changes the basepointed homotopy type of $l$, meaning that there is no homotopy starting at $l$, ending at $l$, and taking the basepoint along such a path (see Hatcher for the relation between conjugation and homotopy).

A homotopy from $r$ to $(lr)^{-1}r(lr)$ necessarily has the homotopy class of the loop of the basepoint equal to a word with $r$ in it. This is because we are conjugating $r$ by a word to get $(lr)^{-1}r(lr)$ (again, see Hatcher for this relation). Such a thing necessarily does not commute with $l$, so there is no homotopy from $l \vee r$ to $l \vee (lr)^{-1}r(lr)$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain a bit more why it is sufficient to show that the loop described by the basepoint does not commute with $[l]$? I understood that $[\mathbb{S}^1,Y]$ is $\pi(Y)/\text{conjugation}$ and the above fact would give us that $[l]$ and $[*]\cdot [l]\cdot [*]^{-1}$ are different in $[\mathbb{S}^1,Y]$ where $[*]$ is the loop of the basepoint. But how does this help us?

Comment: What we want to show is that any homotopy starting at $l \vee (lr)^{-1}r(lr)$ which on the right circle ends at $r$ cannot end at $l$ on the left circle. Since the homotopy class of the map at the end of the homotopy on the left circle is what you get when you conjugate $l$ by the loop the basepoint takes, if we show that the loop does not commute with the map of the left circle into the space, then it has to result in a different basepointed homotopy class. Since any map is homotopic to itself, the resulting map cannot be $l$.